# Long request freeze on MySQL server

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a 5.7 MySQL server with MyISAM tables.

All my tables are used by internal software for my customers. The tables, defined indexes, and storage type are imposed by the software.

I have create some requests to generate reports. My reports work with multiples joined tables and many conditions. A request can take 5 minutes to display a result.

**My problem is not the time because it's really due to the complexity of request. Rather, during the request, all connections are frozen and the users can't use the rest of the application.**

*Do you have any ideas on how I can change this situation? I have already optimized my requests and they can't work more on this side. I am searching for a solution about concurrent access, or other solutions*.

Please note: my requests are "read only".

Comment: You haven't given us much to work with to help you. SO is about programming, and you've said you can't do any further work to optimize your queries. Therefore your question isn't about programming.  So SO probably can't help you. You might want to try on dba.stackexchange.com for help.

Comment: Maybe some kind of Databaselock appears. Please check isolation level.

Comment: You could set up database replication to a 'backup' server and run your report queries against that server instead.  Again this is more environment setup rather than programming.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i close this and ask my question on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: i have posted this question on the good forum :
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176163/long-request-freeze-mysql-server